# SDK Manager won't open

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk

I installed JDK and made a two system variables called:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
```

And :

```
PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin
```

And downloaded `sdk-tools-windows-3859397`. Extracted it and double-clicked the `android.bat`. But SDK Manager didn't open, just a command prompt flashes on the screen.

I can't install any tools to make an android game using Unity.

Comment: Install Android Studio and you will get SDK Manager....

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that as my last resort..haha

Comment: But do you know the exacts commands on using command line?

Comment: You don't need command line. Simply delete the current SDK then Google and install Android Studio.  From Android Studio, install the SDK and SDK Tools you want

Comment: Yeah, maybe someday I'm gonna use the Android Studio too. haha